# how to define arrays of lists in vb6?

Tags: arrays, vb6, listbox

I want to declare an array of Listbox in vb6 and I need help to do it.
I have tried this code:

```
Dim list() As ListBox
```

but has the following error:

```
object variable or with block variable not set 91
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give two or more controls the same "(Name)" property in the form designer, VB will prompt you to create a control array, which might be what you want.

If you need to create an array manually, remember you have to dimension it. E.g.,

```
Dim list(0 To 9) As ListBox
```

Or:

```
Dim list() as ListBox
...
ReDim list(0 To 9) As ListBox
```

But you also have to put ListBoxes in the array. When you first dimension the array, you only get the array itself. All its entries are set to `Nothing`, which is what is meant by "Object variable or With block variable not set". You have to `Set` each array entry to a valid ListBox before you can use it.

If you want to add controls to a form at run time, use `Controls.Add`. For example:

```
For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
    Set list(i) = Controls.Add("VB.ListBox", "List" & i, Me)
    list(i).Visible = True

    list(i).AddItem "hello"
    list(i).Move 0, list(i).Height * i
Next
```